# Using the passwd command from within a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I'm writing a shell script to automatically add a new user and update their password. I don't know how to get passwd to read from the shell script instead of interactively prompting me for the new password. My code is below.

```
adduser $1
passwd $1
$2
$2
```

Comment: Similar question to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94060/run-adduser-non-interactively/667842#667842

Answer (score 114, accepted):

from "`man 1 passwd`":

```
   --stdin
          This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the new
          password from standard input, which can be a pipe.
```

So in your case

```
adduser "$1"
echo "$2" | passwd "$1" --stdin
```

Your `passwd` command may not have a `--stdin` option: use the `chpasswd`
utility instead, as suggested by [ashawley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script/715802#715802).

If you use a shell other than bash, `echo` might not be a builtin command,
and the shell will call `/bin/echo`. This is insecure because the password
will show up in the process table and can be seen with tools like `ps`.

In this case, you should use another scripting language. Here is an example in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open my $pipe, '|chpasswd' or die "can't open pipe: $!";
print {$pipe} "$username:$password";
close $pipe
```

Comment: if bash then `passwd "$1" <<< "$2"`

Comment: @glennjackman please note that here strings implicitly create temporary files that may be readable by outside sources.

Comment: @8jean Relying on echo keeping its arguments out of the public process tree as a side-effect of it being a built-in probably isn't the best practice.  The side-effect may not hold true on all systems, echo isn't always a built-in and seeing passwords passed as arguments should just be a big red flag you should aim to avoid.

Answer (score 80):

The only solution works on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
echo -e "new_password\nnew_password" | (passwd user)
```

But the second option only works when I change from:

```
echo "password:name" | chpasswd
```

To:

```
echo "user:password" | chpasswd
```

See explanations in original post: [Changing password via a script](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/790-changing-password-via-a-script)

Comment: `echo 'user:newpassword' | sudo chpasswd`, or without sudo as root.

Comment: What if the password contains a "\n" in the first case? There is a way to handle this? Such as `my@secret\npasword123`

Comment: Similar to the first but automatically repeats the password. Also, use sudo otherwise it will ask for current password first and mess this up.

`echo password | sed 's/.*/\0\n\0/' | sudo passwd -q $USER 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 44):

Nowadays, you can use this command as root:

```
echo "user:pass" | chpasswd
```

or with sudo as permitted user:

```
echo "user:pass" | sudo chpasswd
```

Comment: For some reason I received the following error when trying your command: "Authentication token manipulation error". Adding sudo before chpasswd fixed this for me.

Comment: @LaurentVanWinckel - `chpasswd` only works with `sudo`/`root` rights. Therefore, to execute it as an user other than `root`, that user has to be in the `sudo` group: `echo 'user:pass' | sudo chpasswd` . When executing this one-liner on a prompt, make sure to prepend it with an additional space. Otherwise the command including the sensitive password will likely be written to the user's prompt history file, e.g. `~/.bash_history`.

Answer (score 27):

Read the wise words from:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/078

I quote:

> Nothing you can do in bash can possibly work. passwd(1) does not read from standard input. This is intentional. It is for your protection. Passwords were never intended to be put into programs, or generated by programs. They were intended to be entered only by the fingers of an actual human being, with a functional brain, and never, ever written down anywhere.
>
> Nonetheless, we get hordes of users asking how they can circumvent 35 years of Unix security.

It goes on to explain how you can set your `shadow(5)` password properly, and shows you the GNU-*I-only-care-about-security-if-it-doesn't-make-me-think-too-much*-way of abusing `passwd(1)`.

Lastly, if you ARE going to use the silly GNU passwd(1) extension `--stdin`, **do not** pass the password putting it on the command line.

```
echo $mypassword | passwd --stdin # Eternal Sin.
echo "$mypassword" | passwd --stdin # Eternal Sin, but at least you remembered to quote your PE.
passwd --stdin <<< "$mypassword" # A little less insecure, still pretty insecure, though.
passwd --stdin < "passwordfile" # With a password file that was created with a secure `umask(1)`, a little bit secure.
```

The last is the best you can do with GNU `passwd`.  Though I still wouldn't recommend it.

Putting the password on the command line means anyone with even the remotest hint of access to the box can be monitoring `ps` or such and steal the password.  Even if you think your box is safe; it's something you should **really** get in the habit of avoiding at all cost (yes, even the cost of doing a bit more trouble getting the job done).

Comment: may I ask why this is 'still pretty insecure'?
$ passwd --stdin <<< $(pass somehost/someuser)

Comment: @JackTang You need quotes on your parameter expansion.  The reason why <<< is less secure than < with a file that has good permissions is because <<< may implicitly create a temporary file that's readable by outsiders.

Answer (score 6):

*Here-document* works if your `passwd` doesn't support `--stdin` and you don't want to (or can't) use `chpasswd` for some reason.

**Example:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username="user"
password="pass"

passwd ${username} << EOD
${password}
${password}
EOD
```

Tested under Arch Linux. This `passwd` is an element of `shadow-utils` and installed from the `core/filesystem` package, which you usually have by default since the package is required by `core/base`.

Comment: Super-evil, but it's the only thing that actually worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use chpasswd

`echo $1:$2 | chpasswd`

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same problem and for some reason the `--stdin` option was not available on the version of `passwd` I was using (shipped in Ubuntu 14.04).

If any of you happen to experience the same issue, you can work it around as I did, by using the `chpasswd` command like this:

```
echo "<user>:<password>" | chpasswd
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who need to 'run as root' remotely through a script logging into a user account in the sudoers file, I found an evil horrible hack, that is no doubt very insecure:

```
sshpass -p 'userpass' ssh -T -p port user@server << EOSSH
sudo -S su - << RROOT
userpass
echo ""
echo "*** Got Root ***"
echo ""
#[root commands go here]
useradd -m newuser
echo "newuser:newpass" | chpasswd
RROOT
EOSSH
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this on a CentOS VMWare image that I keep around for this sort of thing.  Note that you probably want to avoid putting passwords as command-line arguments, because anybody on the entire machine can read them out of 'ps -ef'.

That said, this will work:

```
user="$1"
password="$2"
adduser $user
echo $password | passwd --stdin $user
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the definitive answer for a teradata node admin.

Go to your `/etc/hosts` file and create a list of IP's or node names in a text file.

```
SMP007-1
SMP007-2
SMP007-3
```

Put the following script in a file.

```
#set a password across all nodes
printf "User ID: "
read MYUSERID
printf "New Password: "
read MYPASS

while read -r i; do
    echo changing password on "$i"
    ssh root@"$i" sudo echo "$MYUSERID":"$MYPASS" | chpasswd
    echo password changed on "$i"
done< /usr/bin/setpwd.srvrs
```

Okay I know I've broken a cardinal security rule with ssh and root
but I'll let you security folks deal with it.

Now put this in your `/usr/bin` subdir along with your `setpwd.srvrs` config file.

When you run the command it prompts you one time for the User ID
then one time for the password.  Then the script traverses all nodes
in the `setpwd.srvrs` file and does a passwordless ssh to each node,
then sets the password without any user interaction or secondary
password validation.

Comment: I fixed the most egregious errors in this but this really isn't best practice at all. Hardcoding a local data file in `/usr/bin` is just a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

For me on Raspbian it works only this way (old password added):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username="pi"
password="Szevasz123"
new_ps="Szevasz1234"

passwd ${username} << EOD
${password}
${new_ps}
${new_ps}
EOD
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `-p` option of `adduser` (which AFAIK is just another name for `useradd`)?  You may also want to look at the `-P` option of `luseradd` which takes a plaintext password, but I don't know if `luseradd` is a standard command (it may be part of SE Linux or perhaps just an oddity of Fedora).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to set a password which nobody knows. This seems to work:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c44 | passwd --stdin $user
```

Comment: It's better to disable an account / disable its login than giving it an unknown password but leaving its login active.

Comment: passwd --delete or --lock

Answer (score 0):

> echo 'yourPassword' | sudo -S yourCommand

if -S doesnt work try with -kS

Answer (score 0):

### Auto-generated random password from all graphical characters

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787889/1818110) by @fernando-kosh could not easily be used when the password may contain `\` character because `echo -e` would interpret `\` as having special meaing.

Since I am auto-generating password from graphical character set which may also contain `\`, I a different way to send new password twice to stdout with newline in between. Here is a solution with `yes` command:

```bash
NEW_PASSWORD=$(tr -dc '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom | head -c "${PASSWORD_LENGTH:-30}")

yes "$NEW_PASSWORD" | \
  head -n 2 | \
  sudo passwd "$TARGET_USERNAME"
```

This will generate 30-character random password by default if `PASSWORD_LENGTH` is not set.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [the `expect` utility](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to drive all programs that read from a tty (as opposed to stdin, which is what passwd does). Expect comes with ready to run examples for all sorts of interactive problems, like passwd entry.