# Useradd using crypt password generation

Tags: shell, ftp, passwd

I am working on what I thought was a very simple script to dynamically create an FTP user using 'useradd' There are several parts of this process I am unfamiliar with, and an entire day's research has not gotten me too far. Here is what I have:

```
password="pass"
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "wtf")' $password)
useradd -d HOME_DIR -s /bin/bash -g GROUP -p $pass -f -1 testing
```

Notes

1. HOME_DIR and GROUP are placeholders
2. I am not having issues with the home/base_dir (-d, -b) or group (-g) functionality of 'useradd'

Topics:

1. Why are my password generation efforts not working?
2. is /bin/bash the correct shell to use for a purely FTP user, or would I use /bin/false or a different shell?
3. By default, useradd disables an account until they provide their own password, how do I bypass this?
4. I do not want to use the passwd utility as it cripples my ability to automagically generate FTP accounts, I found a solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script), but I do not understand the solution

Let me know if I am going about this all wrong, or if what I am trying to do is not possible or if I am misinformed about anything I have stated herein. Thank you for any help you can provide. :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Regarding password generation:

> #### [32.3 Encrypting Passwords](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html)
>
> - Function: char * **crypt** (*const char *key, const char *salt*)
>
>   The `crypt` function takes a password, *key*, as a string, and a *salt* character array which is described below, and returns a printable ASCII string which starts with another salt.  It is believed that, given the output of the function, the best way to find a *key* that will produce that output is to guess values of *key* until the original value of *key* is found.
>
>   The *salt* parameter does two things. Firstly, it selects which algorithm is used, the MD5-based one or the DES-based one.  Secondly, it makes life harder for someone trying to guess passwords against a file containing many passwords; without a *salt*, an intruder can make a guess, run `crypt` on it once, and compare the result with all the passwords. With a *salt*, the intruder must run `crypt` once for each different salt.
>
>   For the MD5-based algorithm, the *salt* should consist of the string `$1$`, followed by up to 8 characters, terminated by either another `$` or the end of the string. The result of crypt will be the *salt*, followed by a `$` if the salt didn't end with one, followed by 22 characters from the alphabet `./0-9A-Za-z`, up to 34 characters total. Every character in the *key* is significant.
>
>   For the DES-based algorithm, the *salt* should consist of two characters from the alphabet `./0-9A-Za-z`, and the result of `crypt` will be those two characters followed by 11 more from the same alphabet, 13 in total. Only the first 8 characters in the *key* are significant.
>
>   The MD5-based algorithm has no limit on the useful length of the password used, and is slightly more secure. It is therefore preferred over the DES-based algorithm.
>
>   When the user enters their password for the first time, the salt should be set to a new string which is reasonably random. To verify a password against the result of a previous call to crypt, pass the result of the previous call as the salt.

Depending on your system, there may also be Blowfish or SHA-2 family `crypt`s as well, and it's possible that the traditional DES may be disabled for security.  PAM can add its own complications in here too.

```
     ID       |    Method
  -------------------------------
     1        |  MD5 (Linux, BSD)
     2a       |  Blowfish (OpenBSD)
     md5      |  Sun MD5
     5        |  SHA-256 (Linux, since glibc 2.7)
     6        |  SHA-512 (Linux, since glibc 2.7)
```

That being said, the

```
root# useradd -d / -g users -p $(perl -e'print crypt("foo", "aa")') -M -N foo
user$ su - foo
Password: foo
foo$ ^D
root# userdel foo
```

works just fine on my system.

---

Regarding the shell:

`/sbin/nologin` is traditional for login-disabled users.  You'll have to double-check your FTP daemon's configuration to see if that excludes them from FTP access.

---

Regarding the disabled account:

As seen above, works for me, as expected if given a working password.

---

About the other solution:

What don't you understand about the alternate solution?  It seems very clear to me.

Just pipe "`username:password`" into "`chpasswd`".

---

If you want FTP-only users, I would recommend using a FTP daemon that supports virtual users like [glftpd](http://www.glftpd.dk/), [Pure-FTPd](http://www.pureftpd.org/), [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/), [vsftpd](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/), ... actually it seems that all the common ones do.  This way, an FTP account does not require a real system account.

Comment: Sorry I never thanked you for the response 7 months ago. Your solution worked, thanks :)

Comment: You can also: useradd -p "$(echo -n PASSWORD | openssl passwd -crypt -stdin)" and passwd has the stdin flag so I have not tried it but echo -n password | passwd --stdin user might work.

Comment: what is the `aa`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create "FTP only" users, you should look at [rssh](http://pizzashack.org/rssh/)
Install rssh for your distro, and set the shell for the "FTP only" user to "/usr/bin/rssh"

Works very well

Comment: Thanks! This actually won't work for what I was doing 7 months ago, but it will work for something I'm working on now. :D