# Problems with this command in script Cent0S 5.4

Tags: linux, unix

I have this command in a setup script

```
Running Command: useradd ftpsecure
Running Command: /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
Running Command: chkconfig --add vsftpd
Running Command: chkconfig vsftpd on
Running Command: /usr/sbin/groupadd cdms-users
Running Command: /usr/sbin/useradd -g cdms-users -d /ftpUploads/ cdmsUser -p cdms
        [ESC[0;31mFAILEDESC[0m]
```

Seem to be running into problems with the last command.  If anyone had any idea what could possibly be wrong.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: The `-p` parameter of `useradd` is used to pass the encripted password. Maybe `cdms` is not a valid password.

Answer (score 0):

`useradd`'s `-p` flag (for specifying a password) is not for specifying a plaintext password.

This is the description from `useradd`'s manpage.

```
   -p, --password PASSWORD
       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the
       password.

       Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will
       be visible by users listing the processes.

       You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.
```

You would have to generate the `crypt` hash for the password.

The accepted answer in this other StackOverflow thread shows a way to do it: [Useradd using crypt password generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020534/useradd-using-crypt-password-generation)

Though specifying the plain password on the command line could be a security vulnerability, as it could be recorded in command line history.