# Ubuntu Linux useradd with -p option

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to add a user in Ubuntu Linux 11.04 with a single useradd directive.

I found something similar here but I can't seem to figure it out completely:
[Useradd using crypt password generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020534/useradd-using-crypt-password-generation)

Let's say my username is ohill and my password is justpass, what would the command line directive be exactly? Here is what I have so far that I borrowed from the above link.

```
useradd -p $(perl -e 'print crypt("justpass", "aa")') -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m ohill
```

It doesn't seem to work and I'm sure I'm missing something.

Any ideas or an easier way? I'm looking for something I can easily put in a shell script.

Comment: I wonder why the down-votes, is it a crime to not be all-knowing?

Answer (score 1):

I settled for the following:

```
useradd {myusername} -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m
echo "{myusername}:{mypassword}" | chpasswd
```

It's two lines but it does the business.

So my command line directive given the username and password in my initial question above would be:

```
useradd ohill -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m
echo "ohill:justpass" | chpasswd
```

I hope it comes in handy for someone else.

Cheers.