# Encrypting string with bash

Tags: bash, centos5

I use CentOS5.
I'm trying to read a username and a password in a bash script so I can create a new unix user.

```
useradd -p $password $login
```

the problem here is that the password is not encrypted later in /etc/shadow.

In `useradd` man pages it is meant to specify passwords encrypted with `crypt` which is not a bash command.
How can i use this function from a Bash script?
Or is there any command for encrypting strings?

Comment: pls look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020534/useradd-using-crypt-password-generation

Comment: this is from man page of `useradd` -- `-p : "Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes. You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy."`

Comment: +1 to Bill's comment. When it comes to security, don't take any shortcuts. Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OpenSSL for this. Its `passwd` command uses `crypt` by default.

```
$ openssl passwd secret
xzQbh15rXTn1c
```

Comment: But your userdb should not be.

Comment: True. I'm just answering his question; I'll leave it to someone else to explain why what he's doing is a bad idea and what he should be doing instead, because I don't feel up for it right now.