# linux bash shell: how to create user with username and password from file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm clear about everything except how to set password using the script. Normally, I would write:

```
passwd username
```

And the terminal would prompt for password. How to read password from file instead?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script ?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. My question is already answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
passwd --stdin username < filename
```

From [passwd(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd):

> --stdin This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the new password from standard input, which can be a pipe.