# How to provide password to a command that prompts for one in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, passwords

I'm writing a UNIX shell function that is going to execute a command that will prompt the user for a password. I want to hard-code the password into the script and provide it to the command. I've tried piping the password into the command like this:

```
function() {
    echo "password" | command
}
```

This may not work for some commands as the command may flush the input buffer before prompting for the password.

I've also tried redirecting standard input to a file containing the password like this, but that doesn't work either:

```
function() {
    echo "password" > pass.tmp
    command < pass.tmp
    rm pass.tmp
}
```

I know that some commands allow for the password to be provided as an argument, but I'd rather go through standard input.

I'm looking for a quick and dirty way of piping a password into a command in bash.

Comment: Have you looked at `autoexpect` ? It doesn't get much easier than that. You just just pass it the command and it will record everything you do and create the expect file for you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Take a look at `autoexpect` (decent tutorial [**HERE**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404120518/http://www.linuxjournal.com:80/article/3065)). It's about as quick-and-dirty as you can get without resorting to trickery.

Comment: Wonderful - seeing as how my real intent is to be able to do something quick-n-dirty, this is just what I need!

Comment: Saved me typing the same password three times into my sadly implemented VPN. (I also created a script that just runs ```expect vpn.sh```)

Comment: It would be great to have at least a quick snippet included in the answer here. Links don't *always* work six years later. This one does, but :)

Comment: @Unsigned updated the link to ensure this will stick around for a long time.  Not exactly what you're looking for but Eric's answer gets you there.

Comment: Hinting to an answer is NOT an answer but a comment.

Answer (score 51):

**How to use autoexpect to pipe a password into a command:**

These steps are illustrated with an Ubuntu 12.10 desktop.  The exact commands for your distribution may be slightly different.

This is dangerous because you risk exposing whatever password you use to anyone who can read the autoexpect script file.

DO NOT expose your root password or power user passwords by piping them through expect like this.  Root kits WILL find this in an instant and your box is owned.

EXPECT spawns a process, reads text that comes in then sends text predefined in the script file.

1. Make sure you have `expect` and `autoexpect` installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install expect
   sudo apt-get install expect-dev
   ```
2. Read up on it:

   ```
   man expect
   man autoexpect
   ```
3. Go to your home directory:

   ```
   cd /home/el
   ```
4. User `el` cannot chown a file to root and must enter a password:

   ```
   touch testfile.txt
   sudo chown root:root testfile.txt 
      [enter password to authorize the changing of the owner]
   ```
5. This is the password entry we want to automate.  Restart the terminal to ensure that sudo asks us for the password again.  Go to /home/el again and do this:

   ```
   touch myfile.txt

   autoexpect -f my_test_expect.exp sudo chown root:root myfile.txt

       [enter password which authorizes the chown to root]

   autoexpect done, file is my_test_expect.exp
   ```
6. You have created `my_test_expect.exp` file.  Your super secret password is stored plaintext in this file.  This should make you VERY uncomfortable.  Mitigate some discomfort by restricting permissions and ownership as much as possible:

   ```
   sudo chown el my_test_expect.exp     //make el the owner.
   sudo chmod 700 my_test_expect.exp    //make file only readable by el.
   ```
7. You see these sorts of commands at the bottom of `my_test_expect.exp`:

   ```
   set timeout -1
   spawn sudo chown root:root myfile.txt
   match_max 100000
   expect -exact "\[sudo\] password for el: "
   send -- "YourPasswordStoredInPlaintext\r"
   expect eof
   ```
8. You will need to verify that the above expect commands are appropriate.  If the autoexpect script is being overly sensitive or not sensitive enough then it will hang.  In this case it's acceptable because the expect is waiting for text that will always arrive.
9. Run the expect script as user el:

   ```
   expect my_test_expect.exp 
   spawn sudo chown root:root myfile.txt
   [sudo] password for el:
   ```
10. The password contained in my_test_expect.exp was piped into a chown to root by user el.  To see if the password was accepted, look at `myfile.txt`:

    ```
    ls -l
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root          0 Dec  2 14:48 myfile.txt
    ```

It worked because it is root, and el never entered a password.  If you expose your root, sudo, or power user password with this script, then acquiring root on your box will be easy.  Such is the penalty for a security system that lets everybody in no questions asked.

Comment: This post should not be as upvoted as it is.  Passwords are made for a reason, and this mostly defeats that purpose.

Comment: Screen-scrapers and Robot Fleshy Fingers poking macbook trackpads to certify we aren't a robot; notwithstanding, passing around passwords cleartext in bash is the worst code-smell of all, Someone invent a time-machine and hit me over the head when I wrote this in 2013.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `-S` flag to read from std input. Find below an example:

```
function shutd()
{
  echo "mySuperSecurePassword" | sudo -S shutdown -h now
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. This works perfectly as a quick-and-dirty, vanilla implementation.

Comment: If I have a command `run this_command` which prompts for password, how would you change this function?

Comment: @AwaisKaleem This answer should clarify that it only works for commands like `shutdown` which cause the system to specificially prompt for the `sudo` password. This preempts the need for the invocation of `shutdown` to ask for a password, by first getting superuser permisions via the `sudo` option `-S`.  It won't work for commands which themselves prompt for passwords.

Comment: this is great ! but not sure why I still see the `Password:` prompt ( even though it was skipped successfully )

Answer (score 6):

Secure commands will not allow this, and rightly so, I'm afraid - it's a security hole you could drive a truck through.

If your command does not allow it using input redirection, or a command-line parameter, or a configuration file, then you're going to have to resort to serious trickery.

Some applications will actually open up `/dev/tty` to ensure you will have a hard time defeating security. You *can* get around them by temporarily taking over `/dev/tty` (creating your own as a pipe, for example) but this requires serious privileges and even *it* can be defeated.

Comment: You're right, I understand why this is a security hole, but I'm already in a secure environment so my primary concern is something quick-n-dirty without having to resort to serious trickery. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 6):

## with [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read)

Here's an example that uses `read` to get the password and store it in the variable `pass`. Then, [`7z`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z) uses the password to create an encrypted archive:

```
read -s -p "Enter password: " pass && 7z a archive.zip a_file -p"$pass"; unset pass
```

But be aware that the password can [easily be sniffed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563718/sniff-password-entered-with-read).

Comment: This approach only works for commands like `7z` which allow command-line entry of the password, and the question specifically asked to avoid that approach, since it probably leaves the password sitting around in the shell history and exposed to `ps`, so it is far worse than the other answers here.

Comment: If you want to avoid the password leakage, try: `read -s -p "Enter password: " pass && ( echo "$pass" | nohup my-command-that-reads-the-password & )`  You should then be able to close the window if you want - and you can also add a <space> char before read to avoid even the command appearing in the history.

Answer (score 2):

Programs that prompt for passwords usually set the tty into "raw" mode, and read input directly from the tty. If you spawn the subprocess in a pty you can make that work.  That is what Expect does...

Comment: can you please give a bare minimal example of this ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use :

```
echo "password" | sudo -S mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/usb/;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e '[ ok ] Usb key mounted'
else
    echo -e '[warn] The USB key is not mounted'
fi
```

This code is working for me, and its in /etc/init.d/myscriptbash.sh

Answer (score -1):

That's a really insecure idea, but:
[Using the passwd command from within a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: I don't think the OP is just asking about `passwd`.