# Piping to Git Pull

Tags: git, bash, piping

At my workplace I am trying to speed up my startup procedure so I am writing a BASH script that does it for me.

One of the things it needs to do is do multiple git pull commands

What I would like to do is have the script grab my password once at the very beginning, and then pipe that response into each git pull command.

However echo $password | git pull does not seem to do anything.

Is there a way to pipe into git pull, and if so how do I?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857702/how-to-provide-password-to-a-command-that-prompts-for-one-in-bash

Comment: what he's trying to do is a duplicate, but he shouldn't be using bash to do it when git provides its own mechanism to avoid repeated authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that - use [gitcredentials](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) and the [cache credential helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache):

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'
```

Comment: Thank you.
I haven't implemented it into my script yet, but I did try it in the terminal and it works.

Comment: Update.  I have now updated my script and it works perfectly.