# How Initialize web2py with password in terminal

Tags: python, web2py, initializing

I need create a terminal alias for inicialize web2py, but I dont see how initialize the web2py with password parameter. I edit the "~/.bashrc" like this:

`alias w2p="python web2py -p 8000"`

And I need put the password here too.

Exists some parameter for this ou another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to provide password to a command that prompts for one in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857702/how-to-provide-password-to-a-command-that-prompts-for-one-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -a argument sets the password:

```
alias w2p="python web2py -p 8000 -a yourpassword"
```