# Remotely shutdown all computers on network running Ubuntu - bash scripting

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to iterate sudo poweroff through all ip addresses in my network using for loop. All computers in the network have the same password.

`sshpass -p password ssh $ip sudo poweroff`

The problem is sudo poweroff prompts for the password. I somehow need to send password using the script, but I'm not able to figure out how.

I want to accomplish this without editing sudoers file.

**Update:**

This did the job

`sshpass -p password ssh $ip 'DISPLAY=:0 echo password | sudo -S poweroff'`

Thanks to @dan08 for helping me with -S option.

Comment: Not a duplicate but this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34634948/2448918 . Not the most secure solution.

Comment: I believe you may have better luck finding an answer on superuser.com