# How can I pass arguments to shell script in other command with questions

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a small doubts because I don't know how can I prepare shell script which should execute other command with questions...

It means e.g. that I have to connect with VPN client and need to answer a several question. Accept trusting (yes/no), then choose VPN option (VPN/VPN-1), introduce login and password. I would like to have one script with all parameters (of course exclude password).

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Just have all your answers in a file, say `answers.txt`, in correct order and whichever command needs it, feed it like `command < answers.txt`. If you mean to supply password, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857702/how-to-provide-password-to-a-command-that-prompts-for-one-in-bash

Comment: Ok thanks, but what can I do if I would like to skip the last question and enter the password from console? Is there any possible to do it?

Comment: use `read -s password` in you script

Comment: I need to introduce password manually because its token + password

Comment: Dealing with passwords is deeply discussed in the link i provided above. Although as mentioned there, its a serious security hole. Also if you want to skip some questions, just have an empty line in your `answers.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, its working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answers file works, you can avoid placing the password into the file using replacement token. For example, write '**PASSWORD** in the file, and then use 'sed' (or other tool) to replace it at run time.

Possible to use 'read -s password' or other method to get the password at run-time.

```
read -s REAL_PASSWORD
sed -e 's/__PASSWORD__/$REAL_PASSWORD/' | command-to-setup
```

If the number of items in the answer file is small, and do not change, you can inline them into your script

```
read -s REAL_PASSWORD
command-to-setup <<__ANSWERS__
yes
VPN-1
login
$REAL_PASSWORD
__ANSWERS__
```

Comment: Yes, its working thanks! :) I used the second one example. Besides how can I execute other command e.g. command-to-setup2 in parallel because sleep and '&' didn't working in my script. Of course it's not needed but I'm asking out of curiosity