# How to send input to a program using sh script

Tags: bash

I wrote a script that I thought would send input to the terminal when the program request input. I use echo for this.

```
password=open1234
for I in "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
do
    passwd ${I}
    echo ${password}
done
```

This is basically the form of the program. As you can see, i'm trying to change the passwords of multiple users using a script. The problem is that the input from echo never gets sent to the passwd program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use(It would change all users to the same password):

```
#!/bin/bash
script='
passwd $user <<PASS
open1234
open1234
PASS
'
for user in $(cat user.txt)
do
   $script
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the reference and found out why it is used.

Answer (score 2):

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script), you must add `--stdin` option to `passwd`.

```
echo "${password}" | passwd "${I}" --stdin
```

Comment: Thanks, why doesn't echo work? Does it send to stdout insead of stdin?

Comment: Echo does work and it prints text to stdout. To connect passwd's stdin and echo's stdout you should pipe it using `|`.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. All it does is echo the password onto the terminal, but not to the input stream.