# Creating user accounts from bash scripts

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

This is the code I have to create user accounts from a text file. The usernames are being from the text file, and i want to set the password to unix lab. This script does not however seem to work.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `cat unix_tuesday.txt`
password = "unixlab"
do
echo "adduser  $i"
adduser $i 
echo -e "$password" | passwd $password

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues :

- your for loop is broken (the `do` is wrongly placed)
- passwd requires a special option for [stdin input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script)

This should do what you requested :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in $(cat unix_tuesday.txt); do
   password=unixlab
   adduser $i 
   echo $password | passwd $i --stdin
done
```

Also take into account that there is a [difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/what-does-adduser-do-that-useradd-doesnt) between `adduser` and `useradd`.

Answer (score 0):

Running this through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports:

```
Line 2:
for i in `cat unix_tuesday.txt`
^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this for loop. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 3:
password = "unixlab"
^-- SC1058: Expected 'do'.
^-- SC1072: Expected 'do'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

The `password` assignment is in between the `for` and the `do`. Moving it to the beginning yields a new set of errors:

```
Line 2:
password = "unixlab"
         ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.

Line 3:
for i in `cat unix_tuesday.txt`
         ^-- SC2013: To read lines rather than words, pipe/redirect to a 'while read' loop.
         ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.

Line 6:
adduser $i
        ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 7:
echo -e "$password" | passwd $password
     ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, echo flags are undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

`man adduser`

> -p, --password PASSWORD The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.
>
> Note: This option is not recommended because **the password (or
>   encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.**